# Density functions of normal random variables.

Tags: probability, random-variables

$Z$ is a standard normal random variable.

Find the density of $Y=\frac{Z^2}{4}$

I know the cumulative distribution function is $2*P$ ($0 <= Z <= 2root (y)$)

And that this equals $2*phi(2root (y))$

Where the phi function is $phi (x) = 1/(root (2pi)) * integral (e^((-y^2)/2) dy$ from -infinity to $x$

The density function will be 2 times the derivative of $phi (2root (y))$

I cant seem to evaluate the integral in the phi function. how do we do this integral? Ive tried several techniques to no prevail.

P.s. sorry for the god awful formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The key hint is to use the chain rule.  Let $F_Z(z)$ be the cumulative distribution function for a standard normal random variable $Z$.  Then if $F_Y(y) = a F_Z(g(y)) + b$ for some constants $a, b$ and some suitable function $g$, then $$f_Y(y) = a \frac{dF_Z}{dg} \frac{dg}{dy} = a f_Z(g(y)) g'(y),$$ where $f_Z(z)$ is the standard normal density.